# How to determine sizeof farpointer against near pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    int ar[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{8,10,11,12}};
    printf("sizeof(ar)=%lu;sizeof(*ar)=%lu;sizeof(*ar + 0)=%lu;sizeof(*(*ar + 0))=%lu;valueof(*(*ar + 0)) = %d\n",
        sizeof(ar), sizeof(*ar), sizeof(*ar + 0), sizeof(*(*ar + 0)), *(*ar + 0));

    printf("\n\nsizeof(&ar)=%lu;sizeof(&(*ar))=%lu\n", sizeof(&ar), sizeof(&(*ar)));

    printf("\nsizeof(int)=%lu\n",sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
    sizeof(ar)=48;
    sizeof(*ar)=16;
    sizeof(*ar + 0)=8;
    sizeof(*(*ar + 0))=4;
    valueof(*(*ar + 0)) = 1


    sizeof(&ar)=8;
sizeof(&(*ar))=8

    sizeof(int)=4
```

I can Assume (according to this), that all adresses are 8 bytes long. But that should be true only for near pointers (or offset pointers). But what if the pointer I want use resides in another segment in memory? In that case, according to Intel documentation, far pointers are 8 bytes for offset and 2 bytes for number of segment. That is, the far pointer size should be `10` bytes. But no c program has ever print me that. So how can I determine far pointers from near ones?

Comment: The type of the value returned by the `sizeof` operator is `size_t` , for which you must use the `%zu` format to print (mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to undefined behavior).

Comment: How's that there are no far pointers? I have read Intel doc of my current pentium processor, so there obviously are far pointers, don;t understand this claim.

Comment: In modern systems there's really no such things as "far" or "near" pointers. They are an artifact from old "real-mode" systems like DOS. On modern systems there's only pointers.

Comment: So you are saying there is no paging? No segmentation? How another would be address determine, if in far memory?

Comment: Most modern operating systems use a [flat memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model) instead of a [segmented memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation).

Comment: Ok, will read something about that

Comment: Please update your question with information about the compiler you are using, the CPU you are using, and the operating system you are using. Far and Near pointers for segmented memory such as the older Intel 80xx processors requires support within the C compiler to be able to designate a pointer as either a Far pointer, which contains the segment and the offset, or a Near pointer, which contains only the offset within a segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern operating systems use a [flat memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model) instead of a [segmented memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation). This means that all pointers are large enough to point to the entire [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of a process. For this reason, far pointers are no longer necessary and very uncommon nowadays.

This used to be different. 30 years ago, common consumer hardware was 16-bits which means that a far pointer consisted of a 16-bit segment pointer and a 16-bit offset pointer. That way, it was theoretically possible for a 16-bit system to address up to 4 GB of memory (which normally requires a 32-bit pointer).

Since you referred to the documentation of your Intel processor, I will make some further remarks about the current state of the x86/x64 architecture:

In 64-bit "long" mode, the segment registers CS, DS, ES and SS are forced to 0, so that segmentation is not possible. Only the FS and GS segment registers can still be used for segmented memory access (i.e. as part of a far pointer). However, both under Windows and Linux, these segment registers are not available to the common application programmer. They are only used internally by the operating system. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation#Later_developments) for further information.

This effectively means that, unless you want to write code for an actual operating system (or maybe a kernel-mode driver), you will never have to worry about far pointers. It is possible that your compiler does not even implement them.

Comment: So although I do have CS, DS ,ES and SS registers available, But I do not can access them from user space? Or how can I understand the statement, only OS uses them? And in which situation I would need them? (e.g. what kind of hardware I would have to have for my kernel drive where I would actually uses those registers)?

Comment: I believe you can read all registers from user-space. However, this is pointless for the CS, DS, ES and SS segment registers, because they are always 0. You can however read the FS and GS registers. I believe Microsoft Windows uses FS to point to the [Process Environment Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block) and GS to point to the [Thread Environment Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block). However, changing these registers will likely cause a crash. But these are internals of the operating system, which shouldn't have to concern you.

Comment: And last question. If they are force to be null, then what would happen if it would change somehow (even as no programmer can, just consider it would somehow internally change). Would it means, that it would mis-dereference a pointer (because of the new value in the changed reg.), or it would not matter at all? (The question is to clear whether the internals of OS uses them for many processes - so the new value could damage something or not)

Comment: I just read that my statement that FS pointed to the Process Environment Block seems to only be true in 32-bit Windows, but not in 64-bit Windows. This is written in the Wikipedia articles that I linked to in my comment.

Comment: Assuming that the CS, DS, ES and SS segment registers actually physically exist in 64-bit mode (my guess is that they don't) and that they are not ignored, and if you were somehow able to change their value by "hacking" the CPU, then I guess dereferencing any pointer would cause all memory accesses to load the wrong memory address.

Comment: The reason I doubt that these registers physically exist is that modern CPUs are very complex. My guess is that these registers are virtual, at least when running in 64-bit mode. However, I am no expert. If you are interested in the internals of CPUs, I suggest you read [Agner Fog's optimization manuals](https://www.agner.org/optimize/). The third manual is about the internal behavior of CPUs. However, the focus is on performance issues. Maybe there is better documentation if you want more general information, for example the Intel Software Developer Manuals.

Comment: @Herdsman: Modern operating systems are designed in such a way that a user-space process cannot damage anything in another user-space process. Every process has its own set of CPU registers. Whenever the CPU switches to another process, the register contents of the CPU is saved and a new set of CPU registers is loaded into the CPU. This is called a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

Comment: How can be register loaded, when they are physical part of CPU? You meant the content of registers but not new set of registers

Comment: @Herdsman: Yes, every process (every thread to be exact) reserves space for saving and restoring the contents of all CPU registers.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to learn that for any pointer or array `ar` and index `i`, the expression `ar[i]` is exactly equal to `*(ar + i)`.

With that knowledge it's easy to see what you're printing:

- `sizeof(ar)` This is the size of the whole array `ar`, which is `3 * 4` elements, each element being an `int`. If `sizeof(int) == 4` (32 bits, which is the common these days) then you have `3 * 4 * 4` which is `48` bytes.
- `sizeof(*ar)` is `sizeof(ar[0])`, which is the size of an array of `4` `int` elements. So the size is `4 * 4` which is `16` bytes.
- `sizeof(*ar + 0)` which is `sizeof(ar[0] + 0)`. Here `ar[0]` will decay to a pointer to its first element, to which you add zero, and the result is a pointer, which on your systems seems to be `8` bytes, indicating a 64-bit system.
- `sizeof(*(*ar + 0))` is `sizeof(*(ar[0] + 0))` which is `sizeof(ar[0][0])` which is a single element. And on your system one `int` value is `4` bytes.

Comment: Yes, I understand my program. But that is not what I am asking of. I do not know now, whether far pointers even exists.

Comment: @Herdsman Then most of the printouts in the example program doesn't really make any sense. If you were targeting an old system which still used near and far pointers and had a compiler that supported them, all you would need to do was declare an explicit near pointer and one explicit far pointer, and print the size of each pointer. The sizes of the arrays or its elements are irrelevant to the problem of seeing a difference between the two different pointer types.

Comment: Well I do not have old DOS or similar, but x86_64. I did not know they no more exists, that's why I did know about flat memory model. So yes, it may not make sense, but that was not the reason. How does explicit far pointer looks like anyway?

Comment: @Herdsman: See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer#In_16-bit_x86) for an example of 16-bit C code which declares a far pointer.